# How to get specific element javascript based on style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to acces an element that has a certain style.

This is my structure

```
<ul>
  <li> Hi </li>
  <li> bye </li>
  <li> third one </li>
</ul>
```

The list items are placed on top of each other (last one first) and I can dislike something or like something. Once I do that, it gets a style display:none like following:

```
<ul>
  <li> Hi </li>
  <li> bye </li>
  <li style:"display:none;"> third one </li>
</ul>
```

Now after I did that I want to be able to acces the last element that does not have display:none, (the bye) how can I do this?

I was thinking of something in the form of:

```
var myId = $("#slider > ul li").last().attr("id");
```

But obviously I always get the ID of the item that is hidden since its still there.

Can I do something like select last where !display:hidden ?

Comment: First of: `style:"display:none;"` should be `style="display:none;"`, secondly: if you add a **class** instead of a style and then define the `display: none` in your CSS, you could use `$('#slider > ul li:not('.myDeactivatedClassName')')`

Comment: Use a css class name to both put that certain style on elements and select all elements with that style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I do something like select last where !display:hidden ?

Yes, with jQuery's [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) pseudo-class:

```
var myId = $("#slider > ul li:visible").last().attr("id");
```

(Note: Your `li` elements don't actually have `id` values, but that's a tweak.)

**Live Example:**

```js
var listItem = $("#slider > ul li:visible").last();
$("<p>")
  .text("Text of last visible item: " + listItem.text())
  .appendTo(document.body);
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <ul>
    <li>Hi</li>
    <li>bye</li>
    <li style="display:none;">third one</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Can use `':visible'` selector

```
var myId = $("#slider > ul li:visible").last().attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work using:

```
$("#slider > ul li:visible").last().attr("id");
```

https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score 0):

so your inline styling is a bit off it should be

```
<ul>
  <li> Hi </li>
  <li> bye </li>
  <li style="display:none;"> third one </li>
</ul>
```

You could do a few different things, best is probably just iterate through and check for where display = none, then go to the previous element:

```
$('ul').children().each(function(e) {
   if($(this)[0].style.display == 'none') {
     console.log($(this).prev());   
   }
})
```